# Android project crashes when I click ToggleButton and function is called

Tags: java, android, eclipse, adt

For some reason I can't figure out why my project is unresponsive after clicking my `ToggleButton`. Have tried everything and can't seem to get it to function. Any ideas?

My toggle button in the layout:

```
<ToggleButton
    android:id="@+id/tglSound"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:checked="true"
    android:onClick="ToggleSound"
    android:textOff="Sound Off"
    android:textOn="Sound On"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    android:textStyle="bold" />
```

Project crashes when toggle button is clicked and this function is called:

```
public void ToggleSound(){
    if (Global.btnSound.isChecked()){
        Global.snd.start();
    }
    else{
        Global.snd.pause();
    }
}
```

stacktrace:

```
10-25 01:29:22.760: E/AndroidRuntime(18025): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-25 01:29:22.760: E/AndroidRuntime(18025): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not find a method ToggleSound(View) in the activity class com.garrenkeith.project.Menu for onClick handler on view class android.widget.ToggleButton with id 'tglSound'
10-25 01:29:22.760: E/AndroidRuntime(18025):    at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3686)
10-25 01:29:22.760: E/AndroidRuntime(18025):    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4223)
10-25 01:29:22.760: E/AndroidRuntime(18025):    at android.widget.CompoundButton.performClick(CompoundButton.java:105)
10-25 01:29:22.760: E/AndroidRuntime(18025):    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17281)
10-25 01:29:22.760: E/AndroidRuntime(18025):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
10-25 01:29:22.760: E/AndroidRuntime(18025):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
10-25 01:29:22.760: E/AndroidRuntime(18025):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
10-25 01:29:22.760: E/AndroidRuntime(18025):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4898)
10-25 01:29:22.760: E/AndroidRuntime(18025):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-25 01:29:22.760: E/AndroidRuntime(18025):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
10-25 01:29:22.760: E/AndroidRuntime(18025):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1008)
10-25 01:29:22.760: E/AndroidRuntime(18025):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:775)
10-25 01:29:22.760: E/AndroidRuntime(18025):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
10-25 01:29:22.760: E/AndroidRuntime(18025): Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: ToggleSound [class android.view.View]
10-25 01:29:22.760: E/AndroidRuntime(18025):    at java.lang.Class.getConstructorOrMethod(Class.java:460)
10-25 01:29:22.760: E/AndroidRuntime(18025):    at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:915)
10-25 01:29:22.760: E/AndroidRuntime(18025):    at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3679)
10-25 01:29:22.760: E/AndroidRuntime(18025):    ... 12 more
```

Comment: I have the logcat info on my clipboard. where do i post? new to this. sorry

Comment: Post your class & Logcat.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [Android Developers](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/button.html):

> The method you declare in the android:onClick attribute must have a signature exactly as shown above. Specifically, the method must:
>
> - Be public
> - Return void
> - Define a View as its only parameter (this will be the View that was clicked)

Try

```
public void ToggleSound(View v){
    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I used an application with on main activity which loads different Fragments activities with their layout.
So this method **should be in the main activity**